How to use a Chernoff bound to solve for the number of Bernoulli trials
I have recently been handed this problem to solve:

You are holding a bag of balls, where each ball is either red or blue, though you cannot see the content of the bag. Each time, you can take take out a random ball and see its color (and potentially put it back). You want to devise a randomized test which answers whether at least a 1/10 fraction of the balls is red or not. How many balls should you examine, to have a tester with precision $1\pm\varepsilon$ and certainty at least $1-\delta$, for given values $\varepsilon,\delta>0$? In particular, if the fraction of red balls is above $(1+\varepsilon)/10$, your answer should be 'yes', with probability at least $1-\delta$. If the fraction of red balls is below $(1-\varepsilon)/10$, your answer should be 'no', with probability at least $1-\delta$. In other cases where the fraction is between these thresholds, you do not need to provide a guarantee.

I was told to use a Chernoff bound to solve this problem. I had never heard of that before so I have been researching it as best I can. However, the number of sources that clearly explain the use cases of this bound are limited and I keep seeing different forms of it. Any sources to learn from would also be appreciated!
Back to the problem. I defined my variables as below
$$X=X_1,\dots,X_n,\ \text{where }X_i\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p_r)$$
Then $\mathbb{E}[X] = np_r$. I was able to find the following Chernoff Bounds for the sum of Bernoulli trials online:
$$\mathbb{P}(X \geq (1+\varepsilon)\mathbb{E}[X]) \leq \exp(-\varepsilon^2\mathbb{E}[X]/(2+\varepsilon)) \\
\mathbb{P}(X \leq (1-\varepsilon)\mathbb{E}[X]) \leq \exp(-\varepsilon^2\mathbb{E}[X]/2)$$
This seems lik I am going in the right direction, but the probability is defined in terms of $\mathbb{E}[X]$, however $\mathbb{E}[X] \neq \frac{1}{10}$, which is what I am trying to get to I think?
I am very lost as to how to continue with the problem and how to incorporate $\delta$. Any help would be appreciated!
